# Jenkins: pipeline always returns "SUCCESS" even though build fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**UPDATE**: This appears to have been a bug introduced in `Pipeline: Declarative` plugin version `1.3.5` - downgrading to `1.3.4.1` resolves this issue. Ticket was created at:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56402

---

How do I get the real status of a build when using on a remote executor?

Dilemma:

- Using a declarative pipeline
- Builds are ran on a remote executor
- Build fails
- Hits post { failure {} }
- `currentBuild.result` is NULL and `currentBuild.currentResult` is SUCCESS

How do I access the actual failure when builds are executed on a remote executioner?

Code view:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("test run") {
            steps {
                sh "exit 1"
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always { 
            echo "I always run: ${currentBuild.result} <> ${currentBuild.currentResult}"
        }
        success {
            echo "I'm successful: ${currentBuild.result} <> ${currentBuild.currentResult}"
        }
        failure {
            echo "I failed: ${currentBuild.result} <> ${currentBuild.currentResult}"
        }
        fixed {
            echo "I'm fixed!: ${currentBuild.result} <> ${currentBuild.currentResult}"
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on build-096575a3-e6af-4fff-9ca1-84cc46ba4b86-f9b8d29c in /var/vcap/data/jenkins-slave/workspace/test-job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test run)
[Pipeline] sh
+ exit 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
I always run: null <> SUCCESS
[Pipeline] echo
I failed: null <> SUCCESS
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Posting an "official answer" to my issue):

This is a "bug" introduced in `Pipeline: Declarative` plugin version `1.3.5` - downgrading to `1.3.4.1` resolves this issue. Ticket was created at:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-56402

There are back and forths between users and the devs about whether this is really a bug or not. The devs are recommending NOT to use `currentBuild.result` (anymore) but many are pointing out this is a BC break and causing a lot of issues.

Issue has been marked `Critical` - may get rolled back or redeveloped to be better implemented.

If you relied on this feature, either `currentBuild.result` or `currentBuild.currentResult`, I recommend posting your comments on this bug.

Comment: It looks like this issue has been resolved and released. `currentBuild.currentResult` works fine in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch:

```
                        try {
                        sh "exit 1"
                        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                        }catch (Exception err) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        }
```